# Users remotely connected to Windows Server 2008 R2 gets logged off after 24 h

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine that needs to have a user logged in constantly. We login to this machine using Remote Desktop Connection and then just disconnect the session without logging out.

The problem is that after 24 hours, the user is automatically logged out.

I've tried fixing it by opening the Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, opening the properties for the RDP-Tcp connection, going to the Session tab, and checking override user settings. The problem is that the field End a disconnected session is greyed out. I can't change the value of it.

How come I can't change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this server is the member of a domain. You'll need to disable or modify the GPO that's causing this. There are a couple of ways you can go about this.

- Disable the GPO and change the configuration directly in terminal services.
- Configure the GPO with the desired setting.

**Disable the GPO**

1. Open gpedit.msc.
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits
3. Set to disabled.
4. In CMD or Run, do gpupdate.

**Configure the GPO**

1. Open gpedit.msc.
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits\End a disconnected session
3. Set to "never".
4. In CMD or Run, do gpupdate.

Reference:
[Configure Timeout and Reconnection Settings for Remote Desktop Services Sessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like a good scenario for a service account group that has it's own GPO.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - This may or may not be the best solution. But based on the information provided there's not much else to go on.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't manage the AD server. The guy who does, says that there are no active GPO's that affect this.

Comment: Well, there's one way to know for sure. Run a gpresult or RsoP on the server.

Comment: Well, what do you know. The AD guy was wrong. There is a GPO with "End a disconnected session" set to 1 day. I'll send an email to the AD administrator and ask him create a new policy for this one computer without the limit. Thank you for your help.